# Is there an option to have call/caller graphs link in the pdf?

Tags: doxygen

When it makes the html page it works flawless and when I look at an call/caller graph I can click on another method/function and it will jump right to that documentation.

I have `PDF_HYPERLINKS = YES` in my configuration file and my links work fine for the text but I was wondering if there's a method to enable hyperlinks in the `svg graphs` in the pdf the same as you can in the html.